# How to programmatically check WiFi adb Debugging is enable in android?

Tags: android, debugging, wifi, android-wifi-debugging

Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED flag is only responsive for USB debugging. Is there an alternative for checking WiFi debugging in Developer options is enabled programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

There's [`Settings.Global.ADB_WIFI_ENABLED`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java;l=11574;drc=06c2f46d9ae69e1b21cce2cde5427cf91a2eb527), but it's hidden from the user applications. But it can still be used anyway:

```java
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
if (Settings.Secure.getInt(resolver, "adb_wifi_enabled", 0) == 0) {
    // Wireless debugging enabled (since Android 11)
}
```

The constant could be hidden deliberately for many reasons including the possibility of future removal or alteration. Use it on your own risks.